# How Can I Get a List of the Codesets Supported by my System's Locale?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, locale, extended-ascii

For a given locale, say "en_US" there can be several [*codesets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) (also referred to as "character encodings" I believe.)

For example given: "en_US" the following *codesets* may be valid:

1. "en_US.ASCII"
2. "en_US.UTF-8"
3. "en_US.iso88591"

Is there a way to get a list of these from my system? Honestly, what I'm really looking for here is a *codeset* that will handle extended ASCII, if such a thing exists.

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing in the standard C++ library that enumerates the available locales. You'll have to dig into your C++ platform, and see if this information is available, and where.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ugh, that's like the most depressing comment ever. I cannot seem to find *any* reference on where I can even look to evaluate this.

Comment: On Linux, the `iconv --list` command list the available codesets. Its source code will be the place to look. Generally, any codeset can be used with any locale, and you're just SOL if a message cannot get transcoded to the selected codest.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm on Windows, so that looks like the command that I want, but I can't seem to find a Windows corollary. None the less that probably is the right answer.

Comment: iconv would not apply to Windows, then, and I would not assume that Windows will support every codeset in every locale. That's a feature of the Linux iconv library.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the function would be EnumSystemLocalesEx but that technically gives you the Windows locales, not the locales available to your C++ compiler. For Visual Studio, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx). To match the "extended ASCII" expected by the *A series of Windows functions, use ".ACP" as the code set.

Note that there can be multiple ways to refer to the same locale. In particular, .ACP always referes to a code page which also has a number, but the number is language dependent. E.g."gr.ACP" and "jp.ACP"  use *different* code pages. That's because Greece and Japan have different ideas about "extended ASCII".